# Gson - two json keys for a one field

Tags: java, json, gson

I've read Gson docs and decided to use it. But I can't figure out how can I two different JSON keys for one field. For example, I have:

```
public class Box {

  @SerializedName("w")
  private int width;

  @SerializedName("h")
  private int height;

  @SerializedName("d")
  private int depth;

}
```

For the field `width`, I want deserialize it with key `w` or with alternative key `width`, if first is not found in the JSON string.

For example, `{"width":3, "h":4, "d":2}` or `{"w":3, "h":4, "d":2}` should be parsable as Box class.

How can I do it using annotation or maybe using a `TypedAdapter`?

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding your problem. Do you want do deserialize something like {"width":3, "h":4, "d":2} or  {"w":3, "h":4, "d":2} indifferently into Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to write a `TypeAdapter` like this:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19332412;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.*;

public class BoxAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Box>
{

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Box box) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("w");
        out.value(box.width);
        out.name("d");
        out.value(box.depth);
        out.name("h");
        out.value(box.height);
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Box read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
          }
        
        in.beginObject();
        Box box = new Box();
        while (in.peek() == JsonToken.NAME){
            String str = in.nextName();
            fillField(in, box, str);
        }
            
        in.endObject();
        return box;
    }

    private void fillField(JsonReader in, Box box, String str)
            throws IOException {
        switch(str){
            case "w": 
            case "width": 
                box.width = in.nextInt();
            break;
            case "h":
            case "height": 
                box.height = in.nextInt();
            break;
            case "d": 
            case "depth":
                box.depth = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention that put `Box` and `BoxAdapter` into the same package. I changed visibility of `Box` fields to package visible to avoid using getter/setters. But you may use getter/setter if you like.

This is the calling code:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19332412;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class Q19332412 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String j1 = "{\"width\":4, \"height\":5, \"depth\"=1}";
        String j2 = "{\"w\":4, \"h\":5, \"d\"=1}";
        
        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Box.class, new BoxAdapter());
        Gson g = gb.create();
        System.out.println(g.fromJson(j1, Box.class));
        System.out.println(g.fromJson(j2, Box.class));
    }

}
```

and this is the result:

> Box [width=4, height=5, depth=1]
>
> Box [width=4, height=5, depth=1]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

The same can be achieved within `@SerializedName` annotation as `alternate` names.

```
class Box {

    @SerializedName("w", alternate = ["width"])
    private val width: Int = 0

    @SerializedName("h", alternate = ["height"])
    private val height: Int = 0

    @SerializedName("d")
    private val depth: Int = 0
}
```